# SSRS update local report project from report server

Tags: c#, reporting-services

Is there a possible way to update my local Report Project from Report Server.

**Additional Information :** I have created a Visual Studio Business Intelligence project(SSRS) which have around 150 Reports. After designing all reports i deployed on Report Server. Now, other developers update/changes the reports but i am not getting the updated reports, is there anyway by which we can sync and get the updated copies from server before doing edits. I have not found a solution so far. Downloading and including in project is tedious process.

Secondly, i was also confused that "**ReportParts**" cannot be created from Visual Studio BI. More on that they cant be downloaded too from "Report manager" using IE(Internet Explorer). I downloaded a tool where it downloads all reports (**ReportSync.v1.1.2**) but that too is not downloading locally. Am i doing something wrong or is it just not possible.

Comment: The main problem is that your solution should be in a version control system like subversion, git, mercurial, or team foundation server. They are made to allow multiple developers to work on a project and share all of their changes.

Comment: Yes i use SVN but i am of opinion that ReportServer should be providing these and i might be missing the knowledge.